# Plot3D Axes Label Colour

Tags: plotting

I'm using a black background on a Plot3D image and I'm trying to change the axes labels to be white, to contrast. I tried using

```
LabelStyle -> White
```

but this only changes the axes colour. Help please, I can't seem to find how to change this for Plot3D. Thanks.

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 AxesLabel -> MaTeX@{L, "\\kappa", "\\mathbb{E}[\\tau]"}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Background -> Black, AxesStyle -> White]
```

Comment: pls share the code of the plot. I'd guess you'll need FrameStyle->White or AxisStyle->White but it's hard to try different solutions without your specific example.

Comment: I've actually just realised that the problem is I'm using the MaTeX package for axes labels. For some reason it doesn't like to be white...any ideas?

Comment: again, share the code please or it's hard to help you :)

Comment: try `AxesStyle ->Directive[FontColor->White]`? (e.g., `Graphics3D[Cuboid[], Axes -> True, 
 AxesStyle -> 
  Directive[Orange, Thick, FontColor -> Green, FontSize -> 16]]`)

Comment: Still not working with the MaTeX package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used that package before, but giving a look at the package documentation (http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html) I think the following is the correct approach:

```
SetOptions[MaTeX, "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{color,txfonts}"}]

Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 AxesLabel -> 
  MaTeX@{"\\color{white}\\L", "\\kappa", 
    "\\color{white}\\ \\mathbb{E}[\\tau]"}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Background -> Black, AxesStyle -> White, 
 BaseStyle -> White]
```

> [image]